# Where does Ant look to find your Java Home when using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac

My Ant script won't compile code.  It says it doesn't find a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25".  Which is correct, it should be looking for "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24"

However, I don't know where it is getting the bad reference from.  I seem to have 24 on Java_home and in all my Eclipse settings.  Where can it be getting this other reference from?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse gets his JAVA_HOME for Ant from the `Project settings > Java Build Path > Libraries > JRE System Library` not from Windows %JAVA_HOME% environment variable.
Normally it uses the default Eclipse JRE setting which should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24 in your case.
Maybe some team member altered the project setting to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 and made a commit !?
So you have to check the project settings also, because they overwrite the general Eclipse settings.
Did you already run your antfile in Eclipse with debugmode via `Run As Ant Build...` and
`Main Tab > Arguments > -debug > Run` to get more information ?
Is there some `fork=true` involved in your script ?
Also put some more diagnostic output in your antfile via :

```
<echoproperties prefix="java"/>
<echoproperties prefix="ant"/>
```

to get the relevant settings logged.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify which jre the ant uses in eclipse: preferences --> ant

[image]